# What does the RegSetInfoKey operation do?

Tags: installation, registry, monitoring

The deatil tab associated with the operation says:

```
KeySetInformationClass: KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
```

I'm using Process Monitor (ProcMon) to monitor the Registry changes an installer makes and I cannot find an explanation for what this operation does.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is the same question that was asked here in Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2c0w1f/registrywhat_does_regsetinfokey_do/).

I bumped with the same issue than you did and came out with that response. Based on the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553399(v=vs.85).aspx) and the actual behaviour I see in the binary it looks like it checking a registry key value.